# If IS NOT Category Wordpress - With Multiple Categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have the following code on my page:

```
<p class="postmetadata">Category: <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
if (!($cat->cat_ID=='12')) echo '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') . '/category/' . $cat->category_nicename . '/">'. $cat->cat_name . '</a>' . ', ';
} ?></p>
```

Obviously as long as the cat is not 12, it will show the category name as a link.

If I wanted to include multiple categories i.e.

```
if (!($cat->cat_ID=='12 or 13 or 14'))
```

how would I do this?

Thanks
dvent

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
if (!is_category(array('12','13','14')))
```

Answer (score 0):

"||" means "or", so something like this should work:

```
if ( !($cat->cat_ID=='12') || !($cat->cat_ID=='13') || !($cat->cat_ID=='14') )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Place the list of categories to test inside an array
$categories_list=array(12, 24, 32);
// Then test to see if your category is in this list
if (in_array($cat, $categories_list)) {
  // do something 
}
else 
{
  // do something else
}
```